# Which data type for HTML?

Tags: mysql

I would like to store HTML in my database, what field type would you recommend?

```
VarChar
Blob
Text
```

The HTML will vary in length depending on the row.

Comment: what kind of html files are you going to store? I meant small files or large files like forum?

Answer (score 2):

for this task i recommend storing your html in files and in the database use `varchar(255)` for file path.

Answer (score 0):

Text, since HTML is, after all, text. What’s it’s MIME type? **text**/html.